# /var/log/system.log file not keep write on mac

Tags: macos, logging

On my mac system , /var/log/system.log is not write until  two days ago.
I want it continue to write ,how would I do?

Answer (score 1):

You want to see earlier stuff that was written to system.log?  The system log is "rotated".  When it gets too big, it is moved aside and compressed.  A new system log is created for new log messages.  The old logs are kept as /var/log/system.log.0.bz2, system.log.1.bz2, etc.  You can uncompress and view them with the `sudo bzless` command.

The program which performs the rotation of the logs is [newsyslog](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/newsyslog.8.html).  Its configuration file is [newsyslog.conf](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/newsyslog.conf.5.html).  It is run on a regular basis by [launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/launchd.8.html) due to the [launchd plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) file in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.newsyslog.plist.

Comment: First , I do not want to see earlier stuff that was written to system.log. 
Second ,I want to my system.log continue creating , It was stopped two  days ago, I can't see the log for today , when I debug the application , I want see the NSLog in the system.log.

Comment: newsyslog.conf is used to configuraton rules when the log file is too big. My problem is not this , my problem is how to make the new log continue write to the system.log file.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would have stopped.  Try rebooting.

Comment: I have reboot many times ,it do not work .I think it would be the configuration problem , but I do not know where .